# How would I go about finding the datasheet for an outdated IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

I picked up a digital frame and I want to salvage the screen for another project so I'd like the IC sheet to tell where video input is. The IC in question is CT952B. How could I find a datasheet for an obsolete IC?

Comment: If the IC wasn't made by some big brand but instead from some Asian company, you're going to have a very hard time finding it.

Comment: Some big brand instead of some small Asian company like Sony, Panasonic, Hitachi, Samsung, Toshiba, Hynix, Rohm, Fujitsu, Sharp, NEC, Matsushita.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://forums.parallax.com/discussion/download/73960/CT952A.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiPoOzYooTPAhVBy2MKHYBaCIAQFggEMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNEskLiBR-8i7uZu5cydfCKErPs1pA) may be of some use - although only a block diagram.
From [this page](http://www.hkinventory.com/p/d/CT952B.htm) - probably not too useful.

That sheet MAY be from "SHEN ZHEN MTC MULTIMEDIA CO.,LTD"

No guarantees, but [these people](SHEN ZHEN MTC MULTIMEDIA CO.,LTD) have been playing 
the same game - Parallax forum, 2010.

[May be able to help - 2010](http://blog.zaq.ne.jp/kyotani/article/118/)

Were made by Cheetek.
Absorbed by Novatek in 2008.